# Zooekeeper persistence on the cloud (esp. azure)

Tags: azure, apache-zookeeper

How do you keep persistent zookeeper data that will survive server restarts/outages on cloud environment? By default zookeeper persists to local disk. Is there any cloud-based implementation, especially on azure blob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a zookeeper expert, but it looks like there's a `dataDir` and `dataLogDir` configuration setting. Can't you just set these to reference an attached Azure Drive? Azure Drives are vhd's stored in Azure Blob storage, so they're *durable*. With Virtual Machines, you can attach up to 2 Drives per core (max 16 attached drives).

Also: If you're running Virtual Machines (IaaS), the OS drive (not the temp disk) is also a VHD, which is in turn durable storage. This isn't the case with web/worker role (PaaS). But I figure you're running Linux, since Zookeeper's license only allows Linux installations to run in production, with Windows and Mac only allowed for development purposes (see [administrator's guide](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.5/zookeeperAdmin.html), under Supported Platforms).